# MasterDetail Binding

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, master-detail

I have two Grids, I bind a collection with 1 grid , and in that collection i have child collection , i want to bind the child collection to another grid , in which i am using combobox

```
<dxg:GridColumn Header="User Name" Width="200" FieldName="" AllowEditing="False" VisibleIndex="0" >
                <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <dxe:ComboBoxEdit ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=WorkflowTeamGrid, Path=SelectedItem.SecTeamUserCollection}"  Name="PART_Editor" IsTextEditable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="190"
                                              DisplayMember="UserRoleKey"  ></dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
            </dxg:GridColumn>
```

But it is not showing any Data , I tried with this also

```
<dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=WorkflowTeamGrid, Path=SelectedItem.SecTeamUserCollection}"  x:Name="WorkflowTeamUserGrid"  Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto"
                                                            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" DefaultSorting="false" Grid.Row="1">
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView Name="tableViewTeamUserWorkFlow" ShowGroupPanel="False" />
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>

            <dxg:GridColumn Header="User Name" Width="200" FieldName="UserRoleKey" AllowEditing="False" VisibleIndex="0" >
                <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <dxe:ComboBoxEdit ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=WorkflowTeamGrid, Path=SelectedItem.SecTeamUserCollection}"  Name="PART_Editor" IsTextEditable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="190"
                                              DisplayMember="UserRoleKey"  ></dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
            </dxg:GridColumn>
```

but it shows it as many times as the count of child collection because of Itemsource property of Grid , can any 1 help me to complete this with out setting the ItemSource Property

Comment: If I understand you correct you have a collection with some entries and each entry has a child collection. And you want to show the childs from the selected entry in the first grid. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, i have a collection with child collection

Answer (score 0):

since you are binding in a grid column you can simply bind to current item instead of selected item of grid

eg

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit ItemsSource="{Binding SecTeamUserCollection}" Name="PART_Editor" IsTextEditable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="190" DisplayMember="UserRoleKey"></dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
```

this will bind individual combo to respective collection instead of binding every combo to selected item's child collection

if this does not work straight then perhaps you may have to use template column available for dxg: namespace.